# cut a string when find a match, and then continue finding matches

Tags: php, string, while-loop, wiki

I am trying to solve a problem with strings. I need to search the string and when it finds a match it should echo the match and continue looking for more matches.

I think I found a part of the solution:

```
    <?php
    $string = $view[ingredience];
    $showingre = strstr($string, '<p>');
    $show = strstr($showingre, ' ', true);
    echo $show;
    ?>
```

The string is searching data that are looks something like this ($view[ingredience])

```
<p>100 tsk something</p><p>50 sptsk otherthing</p> ...
```

and the result is that it finds 100 and echo, but I need a loop so it can find 50 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`str_pos`](http://php.net/str_pos) instead of `strstr` so you can pass in an offset. Every time you find a match, increase the offset.

Use a `while`-loop or something similar to keep searching untill you reach 50 (or the end of the string).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regex for this one

```
$regexPattern = "/<p>(\d+)\s/gm";
$string = $view['ingredience'];
preg_match_all($regexPattern, $string, $matches);

//$matches will contains all your numbers 100,50,...
```

Comment: I have removed the g from $regexPattern, because preg_match_all didnt know what the g was. Then I extended the line with print_r($matches); when executed it seems that both arrays contains 100.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] =>100 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 100 ) ).